# Как выделить блок?

Tags: javascript

По умолчанию на странице нет блоков. Они добавляются при нажатии соотв.кнопки на странице. 
И вот, например, у меня на странице добавлено 5 блоков. 
Нужно при нажатии на блок его выделить.

```
 var dashboard = document.getElementById('dashboard');
 var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
 var name = document.getElementById('widgetName');
 var count = document.getElementById('widgetCount');
 var color = document.getElementById('widgetColor');
   var widget;  

    addButton.onclick = function() {
        createWidget(name.value, count.value, color.value);
    }

    function createWidget(name, count, color) {
         widget = document.createElement('div');
         widget.className = 'widget';
         var pName = document.createElement('p');
         pName.innerHTML = "Name: "+name;
         var pCount = document.createElement('p');
         pCount.innerHTML = "Count: "+count;
         widget.appendChild(pName);
         widget.appendChild(pCount);
         widget.style.borderColor = color;
         dashboard.appendChild(widget);                 
    }
```

Как выделить блок (Выделить можно только один блок) ?

```
 function choose(widget) {
        widget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }
```

Но вот `widget` `undefined`. Как присвоить `widget` все добавленные блоки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понял, то не плохим решением будет при клике на блок получать к нему доступ пользуясь "event.target".

То есть, иметь функцию - обработчик клика и в ней менять цвет элемента. Что-то типа такого:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
}
```

Ну и в соответствии, когда создаете виджет, добавлять эту функцию как обработчик клика:

```
widget.onclick = chickHandler;
```

Но всё же, настоятельно советую не менять стили, а добавлять css клас.